# Como listar todos repositórios remotos no Git?

Tags: git, versionamento

Como obter uma lista de todos repositórios remotos associados a um repositório local Git?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize o comando `git remote -v`.

```
$ git remote -v
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (fetch)
bakkdoor  https://github.com/bakkdoor/grit (push)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (fetch)
cho45     https://github.com/cho45/grit (push)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (fetch)
defunkt   https://github.com/defunkt/grit (push)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (fetch)
koke      git://github.com/koke/grit.git (push)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (fetch)
origin    git@github.com:mojombo/grit.git (push)
```

Fonte: [git-scm.com](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes)

Comment: Por que o downvote?

Answer (score 10):

Simples assim:

```
git remote
```

ou

```
git remote -v
```

para listar os URLs deles.

[Documentação](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Working-with-Remotes).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).